# Retrieve model's property value using a dynamic variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I want to retrieve a property of a model which has been set dynamically based upon the user which has logged in to the system, in my hbs file.

Suppose `fromReports` is a property I have set dynamically in the model, it could be `model.fromInstruments` for another user.
Given, `model.fromReports=false` or `model.fromInstruments=false`
and I have `var x= fromReports` or `var x= fromInstruments`
I want to get the value of `model.x` in my hbs.

I should get the value as `false` as both `model.fromReports` and `model.fromInstruments` is false

Answer (score 0):

Ember has a [get helper](https://guides.emberjs.com/release/templates/built-in-helpers/#toc_using-a-helper-to-get-a-property-dynamically) which you can use in templates to do this.

*app/controllers/application.js*

```
import Controller from '@ember/controller';

export default Controller.extend({
  x: 'fromReports',
});
```

*app/templates/application.hbs*

```
{{get model x}}
```